# Salforce login session issue

Tags: android, session

Please help me for login session issue for Android SDk
Hi,

I have an Android app in which we have to login using Salesforce, we have used https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android SDK (Native) .
Below are the session expired scenario:
1. After successful login on https://ABC.force.com from mobile app.
2. I am able to see this link https://ABC.force.com /customers/one/one.app in android native WebView
3. But after 24 hours I am again seeing login screen.

How can I preserve session until user manually logout from my app.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User can get the new access token for session as

Using the refresh token authentication flow involves the following steps.
  The consumer uses the existing refresh token to request a new access token.
After the request is verified, Salesforce sends a response to client.

POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.salesforce.com/ 
grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=3MVG9lKcPoNINVBIPJjdw1J9LLM82HnFVVX19KY1uA5mu0
QqEWhqKpoW3svG3XHrXDiCQjK1mdgAvhCscA9GE&client_secret=1955279925675241571
&refresh_token=your token here

Answer (score 1):

use the below link of salseforce sdk  to get new acces token
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=014:20